# What happened to the arguments part of views 3?

Tags: views

Am I just blind?

(I'm trying to pass the current page's nid into a block where I'm theming a view and want to filter the view by the nid.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arguments are now called Contextual Filters.

Answer (score 7):

They have been renamed "Contextual filters," and they have been moved in the third column that is collapsed by default.

[image: screenshot]

In Drupal 6 (Views 6.x-3.x-dev) the URL arguments are still called "Arguments."

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @João was first and correct, so I gave him the check, but bonus point for the screenshot!